# Saving a blogdown draft post (.Rmd file) freezes my RStudio session if there are any mistakes in a code chunk

Tags: r, rstudio, r-markdown, blogdown

**Context:**

I have a website that I've made using blogdown and Hugo, deployed on Netlify. I'm currently working on some posts (.Rmd files) (in RStudio) that are still drafts (`draft: true` in the YAML header). As I work on a draft, I like to save things as I go.

**Problem:**

If I've already used the command `blogdown::serve_site()` at least once during my R session, then every time I save a .Rmd draft post, it 'renders' the document (i.e. hitting the 'save' icon leads to `Rendering content/post/Post 1.Rmd` appearing in the console, and -if it works- eventually the post is updated in the viewer).

This always takes a long time (at least 5 minutes), and if there are any mistakes in a code block (typo, missing argument, etc) then it goes into a loop wherein it continuously tries to render the document and continuously fails. Sometimes, I can fix the code mistake while this is happening and then the next render attempt will be successful.

More often, however, although I fix the mistake in the code, my session totally freezes; either nothing happens (no error but no more activity in the console) but I can't use anything in RStudio anymore, or I get an error from RStudio (a dropdown message box from the application, not a code error in the console) that says "Save File: Unable to establish connection with R session." In both cases, my only option is to Force Quit RStudio, and I lose any unsaved changes in my .Rmd file.

This endless error loop looks like this (in this case, there is a mistake in an argument in the legend() function):

```
    Quitting from lines 317-357 (Post 1.Rmd) 
    Error in legend("topleft", lables = unique(df.vis$PtType), pch = unique(df.vis$PtSym),  : 
      unused argument (lables = unique(df.vis$PtType))
    Calls: local ... handle -> withCallingHandlers -> withVisible -> eval -> eval
    Execution halted
    <simpleError in render_page(f): Failed to render 'content/post/Post 1.Rmd'>

* Retrying in 2 seconds...

Rendering content/post/Post 1.Rmd
```

....and the "2" seconds becomes 8 seconds, etc up to 32 seconds, and then it loops at 32 over and over again, until it recognizes my fixes or (way more often) it freezes.

I never have such problems when I call `blogdown::serve_site()` which just throws an error and stops trying if there is a mistake in a code chunk.

**Question:**

How can I prevent blogdown from rendering my .Rmd post documents every time I save them?

OR

How can I make it so that if rendering on save throws an error, it just stops trying to render it (but, if possible, still saves my .Rmd file)?

I have read [the blogdown book](https://bookdown.org/yihui/blogdown/) start to finish, and I think that this probably has something to do with [LiveReload](https://bookdown.org/yihui/blogdown/livereload.html), but I'm not entirely sure how to apply these instructions to my specific issue...

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks!

**Update - Session info**

```
> xfun::session_info('blogdown')
R version 3.5.1 (2018-07-02)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS  10.14, RStudio 1.2.1114

Locale: en_CA.UTF-8 / en_CA.UTF-8 / en_CA.UTF-8 / C / en_CA.UTF-8 / en_CA.UTF-8

Package version:
backports_1.1.2 
base64enc_0.1.3 
BH_1.66.0.1     
blogdown_0.9    
bookdown_0.7    
digest_0.6.18   
evaluate_0.12  
glue_1.3.0      
graphics_3.5.1  
grDevices_3.5.1 
highr_0.7       
htmltools_0.3.6 
httpuv_1.4.5    
jsonlite_1.5   
knitr_1.20      
later_0.7.5     
magrittr_1.5    
markdown_0.8    
methods_3.5.1   
mime_0.6        
promises_1.0.1 
R6_2.3.0        
Rcpp_1.0.0      
rlang_0.3.0.1   
rmarkdown_1.10  
rprojroot_1.3.2 
servr_0.11      
stats_3.5.1    
stringi_1.2.4   
stringr_1.3.1   
tinytex_0.9     
tools_3.5.1     
utils_3.5.1     
xfun_0.4        
yaml_2.2.0
```

Comment: Could you provide your `xfun::session_info('blogdown')`? Have you tried the latest RStudio Preview? https://www.rstudio.com/products/rstudio/download/preview/

Comment: Ok, so I just updated to this latest RStudio Preview, but unfortunately, the problem persists.  I've edited my question and added the session info.